# Basic fluid mechanics question on the FME

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Ok, so I've got a question on a basic fluid dynamics question regarding the force-momentum equation (I don't know how common that phrase is, it's the one used in the textbook I have, but basically the Reynolds Transport theorem for momentum changes in a control volume.)

I've got a nozzle firing a jet of water into the atmosphere, I've attached the diagram. The diameter on the upstream end is $D_1$ and the diameter at the downstream end is $D_2$. The flow is steady, incompressible, laminar and inviscid, and the goal is to relate the gauge pressure, $p_g$ at the upstream end to the volume flow rate (which we know to be $\dot{Q}$).

I've chosen my control volume to be the boundary surface of the nozzle. I know the answer to be: $$p_g = \frac{8\rho \dot{Q}^2}{\pi^2 D_1^4} \left[ \left(\frac{D_1}{D_2}\right)^4 - 1\right]$$

and using the mass continuity and Bernoulli equations, I can arrive at this expression. My problem is that I've got a discrepancy if I try to use Reynold's transport theorem. If we let $N = \vec{P}:$
$$\sum \vec{F} = \underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{\text{CV}} \vec{V} \rho \text{d}\mathbb{V}}_{=0} + \int_{\text{CS}} \vec{V} \rho \vec{V} \cdot \text{d}\vec{A}$$

On the nozzle, if I choose a rectangular CV such that the vertical sides are equal in length to the nozzle diameter at the upstream end and the horizontal sides are equal to the nozzle length. Then, resolving in the x-direction, I get:
$$\sum F_x = p_g A_1 = \rho V_2^2 A_2 - \rho V_1^2 A_1$$

where $A_{1,2}$ are the cross-sectional areas of the upstream and downstream of the nozzle respectively, and $V_{1,2}$ are the magnitudes of the horizontal velocity of the fluid at the upstream and downstream ends, respectively. In simplifying the algebra, I get:
$$p_g = \frac{16 \rho \dot{Q}^2}{\pi^2 D_1^4} \left[\left(\frac{D_1}{D_2}\right)^2 - 1\right]$$

My reasoning was that, by my choice of the rectangular CV, the only surface force that would be acting in the x-direction is the gauge pressure at the upstream end of the CV.

So my question is: why the discrepancy? Have I made an algebraic mistake somewhere, or is there some surface force I've neglected to take into consideration in my choice of control volume with the RTT method? Thanks for your help!

Ach, apologies, forgot to attach the diagram. [image: Diagram]

Comment: Hmm, just a thought, but perhaps my blunder is that I've forgotten to take into account the internal forces that the rest of the device exerts on the nozzle to stop it from flying off? That would render the problem unsolvable with the Reynolds transport theorem (without further information).

Comment: I don't think you need the Reynold's transport theorem. I got the right answer just now using mass continuity and Bernoulli.

Comment: I've already arrived at the answer using mass continuity and Bernoulli, my question was why my attempt with Reynolds transport theorem failed, haha. Not to worry, I think I've reconciled it with my head, I didn't take into account internal forces from the rest of the device on the nozzle, so neglected a surface force on my CV.

Comment: Ok, glad you figured it out.